# "[Errno 2] No such file or directory:" when reading from shared drive

Tags: readfile, nosuchfileexception, shared-drive

I am attempting to access files from an organization-wide shared folder (H-drive). By using a normal `df1 = pd.read_excel('H:\full\file\path.xlsx')` gives the error `[Errno 2] No such file or directory:`.

The file path was directly copied from the file explorer window (extension and double slashes added), and triple checked.

As[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169845/using-python-how-can-i-access-a-shared-folder-on-windows-network) might suggest, it must be a permission issue. That said, I do have permission to access the folder in question as a user, but maybe my script is treated differently by the restriction? I have no idea  how that works. I also have not been successful by adding `//HOST/share` to my file paths as I thing the above posts answer suggests. Any hel0p with this would be appreciated.

Another consideration is that my folder path has brackets, slashes, and spaces within it. As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57034171/python-problem-reading-filename-with-brackets-long-path-name), I do not believe this is my issue but thought I would mention it in case.

I have also tried saving the script from within the folder holding the files in question so that the cwd contains those files, but still no luck.

Thanks for reading and for any suggestion!